# Nodejs JavaScript Events

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given the code above:

```
binaryServer = BinaryServer({port: 9001});

binaryServer.on('connection', function(client) {
  console.log("new connection");


  client.on('stream', function(stream, meta) {
    console.log('new stream');
    stream.on('data', function('data'){
    //actions

    stream.on('end', function() {
      //actions
    });
  });
});
```

I can say that `client` inherits the features of `binaryServer`. So if I make `console.log(client.id)` in the events of `stream` I can see, which client generate the given event. Now I want to know if every single event is exclusive of one client, in other words I want to know if `data` happens for every single client (that generates data) and no `data event` will be generated while the `actions` is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're registering a listener to the "connection" event which can happen within `binaryServer`. When a "connection" event happens, the registered listener will receive an argument, which you choose to call `client`. `client` in this case is an object, and doesn't inherit features of `binaryServer`.

"data" happens for every `client`, but will have unique results for each `client`since you register an event listener for every `client`.

If two events are triggered after each other, the callback function of the first event will be called, and after that the second events callback function will be called. See the following example code:

```
var event = new Event('build');
var i = 0;

// Listen for the event.
document.addEventListener('build', function (e) {
    console.log(i++);
}, false);

// Dispatch the event.
document.dispatchEvent(event);
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

[JSFiddle (watch console)](http://jsfiddle.net/vmqrt1ty/)

[Information about JavaScript inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

[Information about JavaScript event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Comment: So, data never performs actions at exact same time for different clients. But one after another instead. Right? @leroydev

Comment: If you'd query a database or read from filesystem within a callback, it will wait with the execution of the callback function for that operation untill ready. In the meantime, the event loop will take on other events, which could be a second execution of the same fallback.